# Scipy Sparse Matrix Consumes So Much Memory

Tags: python, scipy, sparse-matrix

I have a code that needs a function to generate a sparse matrix with a size of 200000x200000 and has 9001 nonzero entries at each row, so there is a total of nearly 1800200000 nonzero elements. However, when I check the difference of the available memory before and after the generation of matrix with psutil package, I see that nearly 20 Gb memory is used. That much usage gives memory error on my personal computer and extremely slows down the code even I run it on a remote computing server.

When I think of a sparse matrix, since the ratio of nonzero elements is very small compared to the size of the matrix, I did not expect it to spend so much memory on RAM. Is there any way to use less memory while creating this matrix? Or, is 20 Gb the expected memory usage of a sparse matrix with this size and nonzero elements, do you have any idea?

A simplified version of my code is the following:

```
from scipy.sparse import diags
import numpy as np
import gc
import psutil

 
before_w = psutil.virtual_memory().available / 1024 ** 2 #MB
def get_W():   
    N = 200000
    N_nonzero = 9001
    # remove the first element in the copy since sparse.diags does not like duplicate entries
    vals = np.random.random([N_nonzero,])
    offsets = np.arange(0,int(np.ceil(N_nonzero/2)))
    offsets = np.concatenate([offsets, -1*np.asarray(offsets[1:])])
    W = diags(vals, offsets, shape=(N, N),format = "csr") 
#    del vals, offsets  
#    gc.collect() 
    return W
W_mat = get_W()
after_w = psutil.virtual_memory().available / 1024 ** 2 #MB
print('Difference : ',after_w-before_w,' MB')
```

Here is my OS specifications that I run the code:

Distributor ID: CentOS

Description:    CentOS Linux release 7.4.1708 (Core)

Release:        7.4.1708

Codename:       Core

Comment: Even just storing all the nonzero elements takes 200000x9001x8=14.4GB, and that's before accounting for the space needed to track element locations. What kind of memory consumption did you expect?

Comment: Total memory use in `csr` format is about: `200000*9001*16+200000`.  That is the total number of nonzero items, their values (8 bytes) and column indices (also 8) plus a `indptr` value for each row.