# Python linear algebra operations for scipy.sparse matrices

Tags: python, scipy, linear-algebra, sparse-matrix

## In short:

I am trying to execute linear algebra operations (matrix multiplication and tensor products) on sparse matrices but I am encountering memory issues.
I have two questions

1. About memory issues when performing a matrix multiplication (*dot* operation) using the CSR format with large matrices implemented in *scipy.sparse*
2. The second if there are any implementations of the numpy.tensorproduct function for (large) sparse matrices

I am also definitely interested in advice for the use of other modelling software (e.g. Matlab) or libraries (e.g *tensorflow*) which are better suited, but want to stress that I will be needing graph algorithms after the above mentioned linear algebra.

### First question, details

I am working with the adjacency list of a bipartite directed graph (using *networkx*).
Using *networkx.algorithms.bipartite.matrix.biadjacency_matrix* i get two sparse matrices A,B in the compressed sparse row (CSR) format implemented in *scipy.sparse*.
The matrices A and B are approximately of shape (1000, 200000) and the sparsity is around 0.4% (approximately 900000 edges).

However, when trying to multiply the transpose of A with B (to get a matrix of size 200000x200000) using the *dot* operation. I get the following memory error

```
Unable to allocate 2.95 GiB for an array with shape (793134830,) and data type int32
```

I saw similar issues in this post [Scipy Sparse Matrix Consumes So Much Memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63540692/scipy-sparse-matrix-consumes-so-much-memory).
My question is: How to solve this problem?

Representative code is below:

```
import scipy

A = scipy.sparse.random(1000,200000, density = 0.004, format = 'csr')
B = scipy.sparse.random(1000,200000, density = 0.004, format = 'csr')

temp = (A.transpose()).dot(B)
```

### Second question, details

Later in the code I am still working with the matrices A, B defined above (shape approximately (1000, 200000) with sparsity around 0.4%).

I am trying to form the tensorproduct of these matrices and getting a diagonal using *numpy*.
If the matrices A and B were in np.array (dense) format (so not in *scipy.sparse*), the code would look as follows

```
C = numpy.diagonal(numpy.tensordot(A.T,B,axes = 0), axis1 = 0, axis2 = 2))
```

In particular, I am trying to construct the 3-dimensional tensor C of shape (1000, 1000, 200000) with elements C[i,j,k] = A[i,k] B[j,k].

The same problem occurs when I try to use the sparse implementation for numpy i.e. scipy.sparse.kron (for the kronecker product).

```
scipy.sparse.kron(A.T, B)

out: MemoryError: Unable to allocate 2.67 TiB for an array with shape (735050737201,) and data type int32
```

Again the same question for this linear algebra operation: How to solve this problem?

Comment: Have you tried the kinds of memory use calculations used in the comments of the linked SO?

Comment: In short: sparse matrix-matrix multiplication destroys sparsity. Nothing uncommon and there is not much you can do. The blow-up depends on the sparsity-pattern / distribution and you should ask yourself if the *uniform random distribution* actually defines your problem (or if that's just for demo purposes). If it does, well... nothing *generic* you can do except for buying more RAM. Problem-specific, depending on where this operation comes from and for what it's used for, there might be remedies like exploiting *reorderings*.

Comment: For your example, this looks like: `dims:  10 2000 -> sparsity: 0.00016375 | dims:  100 20000 -> sparsity: 0.001599235 | dims:  1000 200000 -> sparsity: 0.01587357455`. This means, that in your final example, `634942982` non-zeros will lead to `~ 634942982 * (4 + 4 + 8 byte) ~ 10GB` of memory just for storing the result. (assuming scipy uses 4 bytes for indices and 8 byte for values, e.g. double).

Comment: Your dense `C` would be better calculated with `C=np.einsum('ik,jk->ijk',A,B)`.  Not that it helps with the sparse version.  `tensordot` with 0 makes a (200000,1000,1000,200000) array and then removes a dimension with the `diagonal`.  `kron` is (200000*1000,200000*1000).  `sparse` saves memory relative to dense, but still has to have memory for each non-zero value, plus memory for it's column indices and `indptr`.

Comment: We like to see the traceback when people ask about errors, not just a one line summary.  I suspect your first error is in `_mul_sparse_matrix` in `compressed.py`.  It estimates the result `nnz` based on the matrix indices, and then creates a `indices = np.empty(nnz, dtype=idx_dtype)`.  It will also have to make a `data` array the same size (but `float`).

Comment: `sparse.kron` is Python code, so a traceback should tell us where it's hitting a problem.  But with a `output_shape = (A.shape[0]*B.shape[0], A.shape[1]*B.shape[1])` it's hardly a surprise that it gives a memory error, even with a .004 sparsity.